# Forcing an HTML page to shrink

Tags: html, css

So I've got a page designed, which works perfectly locally in my browser, but when I copy the HTML into share point the end of the page has a long, empty tail. As show here:

[image]

How do I get rid of it? I tried just forcing the height like this:

```
html,body { height:600px }
```

But no dice. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

For those who have asked, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html,body { height:400px; }
            .body1{font-family:helvetica; font-size:8px;}
            .backgroundstory{
            background-image:url('/connect/PublishingImages/partnerandjoin.png');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:right top;
            }
            h2.pos_upCAM
            {
            position:relative;
            top:-35px;
            left:-55px;
            }
            h2.pos_upLN
            {
            position:relative;
            top:-30px;
            right:-105px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftHEAD
            {
            position:relative;
            left:-65px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftCON
            {
            position:relative;
            left:-120px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftTEXT1
            {
            position:relative;
            left:-40px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftP
            {
            position:relative;
            right:-145px;
            top:-530px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftT2
            {
            position:relative;
            top:-665px;
            right:-105px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftGC
            {
            position:relative;
            top:-595px;
            right:-510px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftSU
            {
            position:relative;
            right:-145px;
            top:-600px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftT3
            {
            position:relative;
            top:-725px;
            right:-105px;
            }
            h2.pos_leftMD
            {
            position:relative;
            top:-625px;
            right:-155px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="height:400px;">
        <div Class="body1">
            <h2 class="pos_leftHEAD">
                <div>
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/header.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_upLN">
                <div style="float:right; margin-left:5px;">
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/lnkButton.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_upLN">
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/fbookbutton.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_upCAM">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/cambut.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_leftCON">
                <div>
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/connect.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_leftTEXT1">
                <div style="width:350px;"> <br/>
                    When we met 16 years ago as coach and student-athlete, we never imagined we would be working together as colleagues, asking you to join us in all the great things going on here at the College of Business. It goes to show that you never know when that one connection will make a difference of a lifetime.
                    <br/><br/>
                    That’s why we’re reaching out to ask you to connect with us. Many of you are former students, and many of you have already supported the College through scholarships, faculty, fellowships, and building and program support. No matter what your affiliation with the College is, we want to stay in touch, see you at our events, and get to know you better. Whether you live near or far, good memories, relationships, and a desire to keep giving back is what we have in common. It’s what keeps us connected.
                    <br/><br/>
                    We look forward to your partnership and to seeing you at one of our upcoming events. We hope you connect!
                    <br/><br/><br>
                    Best regards,
                    <br/><br/>
                    Sonny Lubick,
                    <br/>
                    Director of Community Leadership Outreach
                    <br/>
                    College of Business
                    <br/>
                    CSU Rams Head Football Coach, 1993-2007
                    <br/><br/>
                    Erick Olson
                    <br/>
                    Director of Development
                    <br/>
                    College of Business
                    <br/>
                    CSU Rams Football Student-Athlete, 1996-1999
                </div>
            </h2>
            <div style="float:right;">
            <h2 class="pos_leftP">
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/partnerandjoin.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_leftT2">
                <div style="float:right; width:380px;">
                    We hope you will join us for CONNECT networking and major events hosted by the College of Business. We schedule regular activities across the nation, many times to coincide with University football games or other significant events. We look forward to seeing you there!
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_leftGC">
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/getcon.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <!-- Show up! -->
            <h2 class="pos_leftSU">
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/showup.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_leftT3">
                <div style="float:right; width:380px;">
                    By joining CONNECT, you are becoming a regular financial supporter of the Colorado State University College of Business. Funds will support CONNECT events and communications to help keep the College of Business family connected. In addition, you will receive custom CSU College of Business gifts. Your contribution, no matter how large or small, helps drive the College forward by supporting students, programs, and other important initiatives.
                </div>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="pos_leftMD">
                <div>
                    <img src="/connect/PublishingImages/makeadiff.png" />
                </div>
            </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: There is not enough info here to answer.

Comment: Can you add a diff of the HTML source code before and after uploading to sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Whatever you used for that white background (div, table etc.) just add the height: 600px; there and that should do it.

Or if youd like to see where that extra space is coming from, post the code and ill take a look!

Jonah